# Has my site been compromised?

Tags: 7, security

Edit
apparently they belong in the includes folder, were they also are. could it be of any use for a hacker to have these two folders in the root?

---

I've been checking my drupal site and noticed in the root folder were two folders, database and filetransfer:

[image]

I dont know if this is hacked or belonging to some module or stuff, does anyone know something about this?

Comment: Start version tracking your code, like with Git. Then you'll know if anything new was added you haven't tracked before.

Comment: we do, of course. but not the drupal core files. still gonna look into the tracked files, thanks

Comment: Rename these folder, check if your site is still running, if it is still running, delete them.

Comment: Sorry, we can't provide individual hack-checking here - it's not going to be useful to the general population as each person's site could potentially be hacked in any number of different ways. The duplicate has a lot of useful general information in it, but the only way to be sure is to consult with a qualified security professional (preferably one that's very familiar with Drupal)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've been hacked, or just accidentally copied those folders to root, but they shouldn't be in root by default.